# how to go back from same activity to different using back arrow?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have A activity that consists a list of countries.

When I clicked on one country it open B activity that consists a list of images. and when I clicked on one of them it open activity C.

**A(OnClick)-->OpenB-->B(OnClick)-->OpenC**

and when i press back arrow on app bar it should back to  B activity

Anyone has any idea how do I implement this?
Please help me

Comment: Same as you came to B, move to C

Comment: You need to use `Intent` to do so. [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Comment: Your question is totally different from your title, it's confusing. BTW your question is too broad for SO. Please have a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you already implement the "open B and C activities" part of your question ? What have you tried for the "go back to B activity" part of your question ?

Comment: i already implement that open B and C activities,now i'm not able to go back Activity B.

Comment: @NoOne edit your question to make it clear. Add the code you tried to go back to B. What did you get ?

Answer (score 0):

simply add below line in your onCreate()

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

and then add this lines

```
      @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

hope this will help you!

Answer (score -1):

In your backButton you just call finish(); 
**Example**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) // Press Back Icon
    {
        finish();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I did this code but I cannot  able to see my back arrow on the app bar

Comment: add this line to OnCreate getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);